# Observing data from Base ViewModel in extended Fragment is not working

Tags: android, mutablelivedata

I have a BaseFragment and BaseViewModel. I created HomeFragment that extended from BaseFragment. Now I observe a LiveData of BaseViewModel but observing data is not working.

```
// BaseFragment

abstract class BaseFragment<VDB: ViewDataBinding, VM: BaseViewModel>: Fragment() {
    lateinit var mBinding: VDB
    lateinit var mViewModel: VM
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val parameterizedType = javaClass.genericSuperclass as? ParameterizedType
    
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        val vmClass = parameterizedType?.actualTypeArguments?.getOrNull(1) as? Class<VM>?
        if (vmClass != null) mViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[vmClass]
    }
    ......
}

//BaseViewModel

abstract class BaseViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    val isMeet = MutableLiveData(true)

    //.... code to change isMeet ....

//HomeFragment

class MainFragment: BaseFragment<FragmentMainBinding, MainViewModel>() {
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        mViewModel.isMeet.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            Log.d(TAG, "setupViews: a $it") // there isn't any happened
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume: ")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this?

```
val isMeet = MutableLiveData<Boolean>().apply { value = true }
```

Comment: It is same as val isMeet = MutableLiveData(true)
Still not working

Comment: The problem is in base fragment probably. Could you initialise your view model in child fragment and try it? It needs to be work.

Comment: I tried it. Not working. It's too hard to understand.
Observing data work only once time when starting fragment.
After that, with any changes data of LiveData, no any thing happen in observer.

Comment: Are you working background thread? Could you share how you update live data in view model?

Comment: I think I figured out the root cause. 
I updated isMeet from another instance of class that extends from BaseFragment ~~